# Warning every time login remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

The following warning shows up everytime when I login a remote server using `ssh haifzhan@remote_server`, anyone knows why and how to fix it?

```
Warning: the RSA host key for 'HOSTNAME' differs from the key for the IP address 'IP ADDRESS'
Offending key for IP in /home/haifzhan/.ssh/known_hosts:15
Matching host key in /home/haifzhan/.ssh/known_hosts:19
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

My OS is centOS6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete "known_hosts" and log in again. It will ask you to reconfirm.

Or just remove line 15 using a text editor.

This type of problem occurs when the host is re-keyed (as in when a new OS may be loaded or when the server admin decides it's time to generate another key for security reasons). Or when some new machine grabs the IP address that you were previously using for another machine.

Comment: thanks for reply, will it break something if I delete the file? I contains more than 40 lines content..

Comment: You can remove individual lines of hosts having the same IP or DNS name to clear up problems like the one you are reporting.